# remoted freecad and ubuntu command line

Tags: ubuntu

Given a site. input some data there. As a result a user should obtain a freecad model.
The question is: is there a way to create autocad files (with ready models) from Ubuntu command line?
Can't find usefull links((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get install freecad

...

freecad macro.FCMacro [parameters]...

call that command from shell_exec() in php for example